# Converting varchar to dates using str_to_date

Tags: mysql, date

I am trying to convert varchar values in columns which are in a table(csv) that is being imported into my database. Now I dont have any information beforehand about the formats the date might have in the csv file. I need to check all the values in the columns and if valid convert those columns into DATE datatype of mysql. The problem is if I use str_to_date and the date is in different format then the stored procedure throws up an error and stops executing. I need a way to ignore that error so that the stored procedures could complete its iterations.

Also I plan to use the resultant value to verify if the content was a valid date ? Are there any better ways to do it ? Please keep in mind that I dont have information regarding the date formats the original data might have.

eg the date could be '11-Apr-2011', '20110102', '01-05-2011' etc.
There are some 4-5 formats that I need to support. 
Thanks.

Comment: 01-05-2011: is that the first of May or the fifth of January?

Comment: It would be first of May, I will not be considering the mm-dd-yyyy format. But basically I need hack to avoid mysql stored procedure to stop when it encounters a "Incorrect datetime value" error. I am handling the errors/null results myself, I just need mysql to complete its iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know the format of the dates beforehand, you could process all using `preg_match`, like:

```
$regex = '<matches for dates>';
if (preg_match($regex, $stringToCheck)) {
    str_to_date($stringToCheck);
} else {
}
```

I don't know how you would handle the unknown cases without creating multiple cases for them. How would PHP know the format is mm/dd/yy vs. dd/mm/yy?

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply. Actually I am using mysql with Java in my application. Unluckily PHP is not involved :(. Is there any alternative to preg_match in mysql ?

Comment: Silly Stack, I had PHP filter on :( You can use "LIKE" which has pattern match capabilities although you'd have to specify each specific date pattern. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Comment: Ok, I will give it try. Btw do you think REGEXP in mysql would be helpful in this case ?

Comment: @citizenen - specific to your PHP point, PHP `strtotime()` function assumes mm/dd/yyyy if the date has slashes, and dd-mm-yyyy if it uses dash or dot separators.

Comment: REGEXP and LIKE are the same except "A REGEXP pattern match succeeds if the pattern matches anywhere in the value being tested. (This differs from a LIKE pattern match, which succeeds only if the pattern matches the entire value." (from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html)